# How to enumerate dates between two dates with moment JS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-format, bootstrap-table

Currently using the Bootstrap Table library by wenzhixin. I'm trying to find a way to set up a filter that use the data range principle.

This code "https://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/06pg2wms/11/" is working fine but it doesn't work when the format of date (in the bootstrap table) is like this : YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.
Does someone know a way to solve this ?

Code works with this type of date format :

```
<tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1">
        <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1">2019-02-01</td>
        <td>0</td>
       </tr>
       
        <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">2019-02-02</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       
        <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
        <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">2019-02-03</td>
        <td>2</td>
       </tr>
```

But I want something that work with these dates format :

```
     <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1">
        <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1">2019-02-01 13:21:30</td>
        <td>0</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">2019-02-02 15:23:11</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>

      <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">2019-02-02 15:23:11</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
        <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">2019-02-03 20:21:43</td>
        <td>2</td>
       </tr>

       <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
        <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">2019-02-03 20:21:43</td>
        <td>2</td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: As you discovered while writing this question, we want to see the code you've tried, **in the question** not on some random other site. So please, copy just enough of the code from that other site here to make an [mre]. See [ask] for more things you can do to help your questions not get downvoted or closed.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code :

```
$(function() 
  {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  }
  )
  
//Moment.JS Return Date Ranges
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = [];
    var currentDate = moment(startDate);
    var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dateArray;
}
 
  
  $('#ok').click( function() 
  { 

    var $table = $('#table')
    var from=$("input[type=date][name=date1]" ).val();
    var to=$("input[type=date][name=date2]" ).val();
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy',{ ETA: getDates(from,to)}) 
        
    
 
})
```

HTML code :

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <div class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span>From Date </span>
      <input name="date1" class="form-control w70" type="date" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <span>To Date </span>
      <input name="date2" class="form-control w70" type="date">
    </div>
    <button id="ok" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>    

<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="ETA">Date</th>
        <th data-field="number">Number</th>
    </tr>
    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1">
        <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1">2019-02-01</td>
        <td>0</td>
       </tr>
       
        <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">2019-02-02</td>
        <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       
        <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
        <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">2019-02-03</td>
        <td>2</td>
       </tr>
       
       
        <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
        <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-4">2019-02-04</td>
        <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       
       
        <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
        <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-5">2019-02-05</td>
        <td>4</td>
       </tr>
       
       
        <tr id="tr-id-6" class="tr-class-6">
        <td id="td-id-6" class="td-class-6">2019-02-06</td>
        <td>5</td>
       </tr>
       
        
        <tr id="tr-id-7" class="tr-class-7">
        <td id="td-id-7" class="td-class-7">2019-02-07</td>
        <td>6</td>
       </tr>
       
        
        <tr id="tr-id-8" class="tr-class-8">
        <td id="td-id-8" class="td-class-8">2019-02-08</td>
        <td>7</td>
       </tr>
       
        
        <tr id="tr-id-9" class="tr-class-9">
        <td id="td-id-9" class="td-class-9">2019-02-09</td>
        <td>8</td>
       </tr>
       
       
        
        <tr id="tr-id-10" class="tr-class-10">
        <td id="td-id-10" class="td-class-10">2019-02-10</td>
        <td>9</td>
       </tr>
       
  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).